# Dual booted computer Ubuntu/Windows never wakes up from sleep

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, multi-boot, windows-11

I have an Acer laptop that I have dual-booted with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11. Whenever I lock the screen of my laptop/close the screen and the computer goes to sleep, I can never wake it up from sleep. I have to hold the power button, force shutdown the laptop and then start it again.

It's highly inconvenient since I have to move around a lot and I have to spend 30-45 seconds switching it off and on again. Is there any way to fix this?

EDIT: Happens on the Linux side of things

Comment: It's highly inconvenient since I have to move around a lot   ......  Have you considered using Virtual Machines?  That is how I do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this issue present when waking up from sleep in *Windows 11* or from sleep in *Ubuntu*, or from sleep in *both* OS's? If one works, and not the other, then troubleshoot that OS. BTW, there are a number of dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machines which I maintain that have *no* such difficulty. However, be sure that Windows Hibernate an Fast Startup are *not* turned on when using Linux, because the Windows partitions will be marked "dirty" and should not be used to write Linux data.

Comment: does this happen on the windows side or the ubuntu side?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This happpens on the Linux side

Comment: @Mastaxx Linux side

Comment: sure it goes to sleep and not hibernate?